# Grok pattern/Regex to parse string with nested parenthesis

Tags: regex, logging, grok

I am trying to parse out several dynamic strings via Grok/Regex that exist in log messages between `()`. For example (`SenderPartyName` below):

```
2021/05/23 16:01:26.094 High Messaging.Message.Delivered Id(ci1653336085475.12327434@test_te) MessageId(EPIUM#1130754#84601671) SenderPartyName(Mcdonalds (CFH) Restaurant Glen) ReceiverPartyName(TEST_HERE_AGAIN) SenderRoutingId(08Mdsfkm853)
```

I would want to parse each key-value out from the string that follow the () format. Here is my grok pattern so far. I've been testing with https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

```
%{DATESTAMP:ts} %{WORD:loglevel} %{DATA:reason}\s ?(Id\(%{DATA:id}\))? ?(MessageId\(%{DATA:originalmessageid}\))? ?(SenderPartyName\((?<senderpartyname>.+?\).+?)\))? ?(ReceiverPartyName\(%{DATA:receiverpartyname}\))? ?(SenderRoutingId\(%{DATA:senderroutingid}\))?
```

This works when there are `()` within the nested string like this:
`Mcdonalds (CFH) Restaurant Glen`

...but it is dynamic and could appear without () like such: `Mcdonalds Restaurant Glen`

Trying to build regex to account for both scenarios with this portion of the grok pattern:

`?(SenderPartyName\((?<senderpartyname>.+?\).+?)\))?`

Currently this parses the non-parenthesis case like this though:

```
  "senderpartyname": "Mcdonalds Restaurant Glen) ReceiverPartyName(TEST_HERE_AGAIN"
```

..where desired state is one of the following depending on the string:

```
"senderpartyname": "Mcdonalds Restaurant Glen"
```

or

```
"senderpartyname": "Mcdonalds (CFH) Restaurant Glen"
```

Comment: Try `%{DATESTAMP:ts}\s+%{WORD:loglevel}\s+%{DATA:reason}(?:\s+Id\(%{DATA:id}\))?(?:\s+MessageId\(%{DATA:originalmessageid}\))?(?:\s+SenderPartyName(?<aux>\((?<senderpartyname>(?:[^()]++|\g<aux>)*)\)))?(?:\s+ReceiverPartyName\(%{DATA:receiverpartyname}\))?(?:\s+SenderRoutingId\(%{DATA:senderroutingid}\))?`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work unfortunately (tested in debugger)

Comment: Aha, try `%{DATESTAMP:ts}\s+%{WORD:loglevel}\s+%{DATA:reason}\s+Id\(%{DATA:id}\)(?:\s+MessageId\(%{DATA:originalmessageid}\))?(?:\s+SenderPartyName(?<senderpartyname>\((?:[^()]++|\g<senderpartyname>)*\)))?(?:\s+ReceiverPartyName\(%{DATA:receiverpartyname}\))?(?:\s+SenderRoutingId\(%{DATA:senderroutingid}\))?` now. It seems to work in the debugger.

Comment: Nice thank you! Is there a way to remove the outer parenthesis from the parsed result? I tried adding some escape characters to the pattern you provided but it seems to error out. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Oniguruma is bad at this.

Comment: Can you accept a solution with parentheses in that field? I doubt there is a way to get rid of them with just regex (it is not PCRE unfortunately).

Comment: Yeah its better than getting the string cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
%{DATESTAMP:ts}\s+%{WORD:loglevel}\s+%{DATA:reason}\s+Id\(%{DATA:id}\)(?:\s+MessageId\(%{DATA:originalmessageid}\))?(?:\s+SenderPartyName(?<senderpartyname>\((?:[^()]++|\g<senderpartyname>)*\)))?(?:\s+ReceiverPartyName\(%{DATA:receiverpartyname}\))?(?:\s+SenderRoutingId\(%{DATA:senderroutingid}\))?
```

Note I revamped it so that all optional fields match one or more whitespaces and the fields as obligatory patterns, but they are made optional as a sequence, which makes matching more efficient.

The main thing changed is `(?:\s+SenderPartyName(?<senderpartyname>\((?:[^()]++|\g<senderpartyname>)*\)))?`, it matches

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `SenderPartyName` - a fixed word
  - `(?<senderpartyname>\((?:[^()]++|\g<senderpartyname>)*\))` - Group "senderpartyname": `(` (matched with `\(`), then zero or  more repetitions of any char other than `(` and `)` or the Group "senderpartyname" pattern recursed ( see `(?:[^()]++|\g<senderpartyname>)*`) and then a `)` char (matched with `\)`)
- `)?` - end of the group, one or zero repetitions (optional)